# GLKTextureInfo used With Self - Crash on iPad Air?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, self, glkit

I have an app which has been working fine on previous iterations of the `iPad`, but crashes on the new `iPad Air`.

The crash is happening at this line with the error `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` :

```
self.textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfData:imageData options:options error:&error];     
if (self.textureInfo == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading texture file %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return nil;
}
```

I am trying to troubleshoot this problem. Can anyone suggest why this might be a problem on the air, while exactly the same code works on all other devices ? This code is running on a thread.

Comment: Is there any possibility of simultaneous access to the OpenGL ES context this is on? This sounds to me like a race condition that's now being triggered by the slightly different performance characteristics of the iPad Air.

Comment: Hi Brad - I think this could be possible. How can I prevent / troubleshoot this ?

Comment: I usually use a serial dispatch queue for each context and dispatch to it anything that touches that context. That guarantees serial access, yet avoids expensive locks. It's also pretty easy to implement.

Comment: I only have one context which I pass down when creating the object - i.e in this case PolygonObject * newStand = [[PolygonObject alloc]initWithVertices:stand.sortedVertices effect:self.effect withContext:self.context andStatusColour:[UIColor grayColor] standLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stand.standNumber]];

Comment: This is wrapped in dispatch_async(newQueue, ^{

Comment: Brad - thanks - this helped me solve the problem. The context was being accessed by some clear screen code while the thread was executing. Happy to accept an answer if you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this out, I'll restate what I did in my comment above:

Generally, when I've encountered odd OpenGL ES crashes like this that suddenly appear on one class of device or another, I always check for simultaneous accesses to the same OpenGL ES context. If you access a given OpenGL ES context from multiple threads at the same time, bad things will happen, including crashes like this.

My preferred way of handling this is to wrap accesses to a given OpenGL ES context in blocks on a GCD serial dispatch queue. That guarantees safe access to the context without the overhead of locks. It's also pretty easy to implement in your code.